# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.flume.tools.VersionInfo, try flume installed failed

Tags: flume-ng

I came across the error:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.flume.tools.VersionInfo

when I run ./flume-ng version

I have set the environment variables either in .bash_profile or flume-env.sh,
the FLUME_CLASSPATH is also set.

What's the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I don't know what is the reason and why did the error happen.

But it works well the next day, flume-ng is ok

and when you start the flume-ng agent,you need to specify the directory,the long one instead the short one,that's the whole path on your computer,and agent can work.